# How to display a fileSystemList list in as3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, filesystems, air

I am working on an air-application but written in as3.
How can I still display an fileSystemList-Component(flex) written in actionscript?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fileSystemList i also Available for AIR Since AIR1.1 see [API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/FileSystemList.html)

also see [About file system controls](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSacd9bdd0c5c09f4a-690d4877120e8b878b0-7ffe.html#WSacd9bdd0c5c09f4a-690d4877120e8b878b0-7ff6)

EDITED Please find AIR APP sample using action script to Create **FileSystemDataGrid**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication 
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    layout="absolute"
    creationComplete="{onCreationComplet()}">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.FileSystemDataGrid;

            private var fileSystemDataGrid:FileSystemDataGrid;

            private function onCreationComplet():void
            {
                fileSystemDataGrid = new FileSystemDataGrid();
                fileSystemDataGrid.directory = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('');
                fileSystemDataGrid.percentHeight = 100;
                fileSystemDataGrid.percentWidth = 100;
                this.addChild(fileSystemDataGrid);
            }


        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Hopes that helps

Comment: that would be the mxml approach, but I am using plain as3/air

Comment: I have added AS3+AIR sample in which i am developing "FileSystemDataGrid" using AS3 and using "addChild()" method of default "WindowedApplication" to add "FileSystemDataGrid" as its child.